# Can I detach an object from an NHibernate session?

Tags: .net, nhibernate

If I've gotten a persistent object from the database via NHibernate's Get() or Load() methods, is there a way for me to detach that object from its NHibernate session so that changes to it will not automatically be persisted?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Try Session's Evict method.

> Changes to the instance will not be
>   synchronized with the database. This
>   operation cascades to associated
>   instances if the association is mapped
>   with cascade="all" or
>   cascade="all-delete-orphan".